# Need exact word in a output text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get a single word output text file from another text file.

For example,

I am having "output.txt" file which contains,

```
179fc059      fastboot
```

now i need the particular text from that file. I need "179fc059" text as an output in one file. And "fastboot" text as an output in another file.

file1.txt  » contains » 179fc059
file2.txt » contains » fastboot

I hope i have clearly explained. i need those two separate words from output.txt file into two separate text files. (file1.txt and file2.txt)

Am running the program,

```
@echo off
cls
set /p a=<output.txt | 179fc059
set /p b=<output.txt | fastboot
echo %a% >file1.txt
echo %b% >file2.txt
pause
exit
```

But i didn't get any output. ends up with error. Even i donno its right or wrong.. Please help me pls guys... So many thx in future..

Answer (score 1):

`set /p` always gets a whole line. To split it up, it's not the right tool. Use a `for` loop instead:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file.txt) do (
  >file1.txt echo %%a
  >file2.txt echo %%b
)
```

Note, that tabs and spaces are standard delimiters, so it's not necessary here to define `delims`.

Comment: Thank u very much it works. And one more question. What to do if those two words (179fc059 fastboot) in the second or third line (row) ..

Comment: `for` processes each (non-empty) line, so if there are more entries, all of them will be splitted to the two output files. Empty lines will be ignored. The rest heavily depends on your real data...

Comment: In my real data those two words are in third row. And the first and second row was not empty, they too contains some strings. here is the actual real file data » https://ibb.co/ggojh5

Comment: hmmm... how to decide which line is the right one? Always the last?

Comment: for now i need last line. may be in future i need 2nd line too. So what to do if i need 2nd line in a out put files ? (142ed056 fastboot)